# Running PHP remotely via SSH

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, ssh

I have a video encoding server set up on Laravel Forge with nginx. I'm trying to run a testing script to encode a video remotely via SSH, using the [LaravelCollective SSH package](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/ssh).

**This is my testing script (index.php)**

```
<?php
exec("ffmpeg -I input.mpg -c:v libx264 -preset faster -crf 22 -c:a aac -strict experimental -movflags +faststart -vf scale=360:-1 output.mp4 1> output.txt 2>&1");
```

When I SSH into the server and run the script from the command line it works: the video is encoded; the script is working.

```
$ php /home/forge/mydomainname.com/public/test/index.php
```

However, when I run the same command locally in my Laravel app - using the SSH package - it doesn't encode and I receive no output; the browser just returns a white page.

```
SSH::run('php /home/forge/mydomainname.com/public/test/index.php', function($line) {
    echo $line.PHP_EOL;
});
```

However however, if I open `index.php`, comment out the FFmpeg command and add some code to check if `exec` is enabled, it *will* execute and send output, so I know that the SSH package is actually working and executing the script remotely.

```
<?php
// exec("ffmpeg -I input.mpg -c:v libx264 -preset faster -crf 22 -c:a aac -strict experimental -movflags +faststart -vf scale=360:-1 output.mp4 1> output.txt 2>&1");

if(function_exists('exec')) {
    echo "exec is enabled";
} else {
    echo "exec is disabled";
}
```

It will return "exec is enabled" to my browser.

To sum up:

1. The script will encode video when running it via the command line on the server.
2. The script will **not** encode video when running it remotely.
3. The script **will** execute when running it remotely.
4. WTH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

From within my Laravel app I decided to try `echo exec('whoami');` and see if that returned anything to the browser. It did, so I knew `exec()` was working and I could trigger it via the SSH package.

Then I realized that my ffmpeg encoding command was suppressing output with `2>&1`. I removed that and finally saw what was going on: I was receiving a "file not found" error, which was weird because `input.mpg` is in the same directory as `index.php`.

This has worked on three other servers, but not on this one created with Forge.

So I added the full path to the input file and voilà! It works!

```
exec("ffmpeg -i /home/forge/mydomainname.com/public/test/input.mpg -c:v libx264 -preset faster -crf 22 -c:a aac -strict experimental -movflags +faststart -vf scale=360:-1 /home/forge/mydomainname.com/public/test/output.mp4 1> /home/forge/mydomainname.com/public/test/output.txt ");
```